# SQL Server 2008 query, time in each status

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm wondering if anybody can help with a query I am working on. I'm trying to gather information for 'Time in each status' from my call activity table.

I need to set up 3 time ranges in days: <3 days, 4-5 days, 6+ days, returning the number of days each CallID is spending in each status.

The trouble I'm having is that I need to identify from the table below when there was a status change. This table records any activity to the call, i.e changed customer details and not just when a status has been changed.

Apologies if this is unclear, let me know if you need further details.

I'm using SQL Server 2008. Here is the table I'm using and related values:

```
CREATE TABLE Activity ( CallID varchar(30), Call_Date datetime, [User] varchar(30), Status varchar(10) );

INSERT INTO Activity VALUES (366,'2013/09/27 12:24:33',13,9);
INSERT INTO Activity VALUES (366,'2013/09/28 17:36:14',13,9);
INSERT INTO Activity VALUES (366,'2013/09/29 07:29:18',13,10);
INSERT INTO Activity VALUES (366,'2013/09/30 06:22:12',13,-1);
INSERT INTO Activity VALUES (367,'2013/09/27 12:13:16',9,6);
INSERT INTO Activity VALUES (367,'2013/09/27 12:25:03',9,6);
INSERT INTO Activity VALUES (367,'2013/09/29 12:25:29',9,6);
INSERT INTO Activity VALUES (367,'2013/09/30 12:45:55',9,7);
INSERT INTO Activity VALUES (367,'2013/10/01 12:46:04',9,8);
INSERT INTO Activity VALUES (367,'2013/10/02 15:12:27',9,-1);
INSERT INTO Activity VALUES (368,'2013/08/01 15:09:01',5,10);
INSERT INTO Activity VALUES (368,'2013/08/02 14:11:20',5,13);
INSERT INTO Activity VALUES (368,'2013/08/04 16:41:11',5,13);
INSERT INTO Activity VALUES (368,'2013/08/05 01:12:56',5,-1);
```

Desired Output 1: E.g. if CallID 35931 took 2 days to change from status 1 to status 2, 2 days would be added to the count in the `<3 column`

```
Status  <3 Days  4-5 days  6+ Days
------  -------  --------  -------
1       10       3         1
2       8        1         2
3       5        3         1
```

I'm stuck in the first stage trying to identify the rows where there are status changes and ignoring the rest. I'm working on a subquery which selects the top date for each change of status. It's bringing back negative values. See here:

```
select CallID, T2.[status], Call_Date,
sum(datediff(dd, nextDate, [Call_Date]) - (datediff(wk, nextDate, [Call_Date]) * 2) -
case when datepart(wk, nextDate) = 1 then 1 else 0 end +
case when datepart(wk, [Call_Date]) = 7 then 1 else 0 end) as TotalDays

from (select *,
(select MAX( T0.[Call_Date])
from [Activity] T0
where T0.[Call_Date] > T1.[Call_Date] and
T0.CallID = T1.CallID
) as nextDate
from [Activity] T1
) T2

where T2.[status] <> '-1'
group by Call_Date, T2.[status], CallID
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: In your example data you have status values of -1, 10, 13, 6, 7, 8, 9. Your expected result shows status values of 1, 2, 3. ?

Comment: Apologies, the "insert into" values are purely a selection of rows from my table(500+ rows) to show the issue i'm facing. Status values range from -1(closed status) right up to 15 in the complete table.

Comment: what would be the expected result for the data you gave?

Answer (score 0):

First of all i think that you need only the rows with the minimum date for each id and status as they would show a status change. This can be done with a CTE and using ROW_NUMBER.

Then you should join the results in a way that on the same record you would have the old status date and the new status date. On the first time you would have nulls for the first status.

```
;WITH CallsCTE AS
(
    SELECT CallId,
                   Call_Date,
                   Status,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CallId, Status ORDER BY Call_Date) AS rn
    FROM Activity
),
StatusChangesCTE AS
(
    SELECT CallID,
                   Call_Date,
                   Status
    FROM CallsCTE
    WHERE rn = 1
)
SELECT Sold.*,
               Snew.*
FROM StatusChangesCTE Snew
            LEFT JOIN StatusChangesCTE Sold
            ON Snew.CallID = Sold.CallID
            AND Sold.Call_Date = (SELECT MAX(Call_Date) FROM StatusChangesCTE WHERE CallID = Sold.CallID AND Call_Date < Snew.Call_Date)
```

I think that you can find your way using the above, as you could use DateDiff on Snew.Call_Date and Sold.Call_Date to find the time needed for a status change.

Let me know if you need any more assistance.